# Change array of elements to objects with static key value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So, I have an array as follows.

```
Array.from(Array(3).keys())
//=> [0, 1, 2]
```

I wanted to convert this array to object and assign a static key called `value` to each elements.

So the final result should be

```
result = [
{
value: 0,
},
 {
value: 1,
},
{
value: 2,
}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) it:

```js
const source = Array.from(Array(3).keys());
const result = source.map(x => ({value: x}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution

```js
console.log(Array.from(Array(3).keys()).map(x => ({value: x})))
```

Answer (score 1):

Any time you need to modify an array, the `map` method is usually the thing to use. It will essentially loop through the array and return a new value based on what you choose to return.

For this, we are just assigning a static key for each value.

```js
console.log(Array.from(Array(3).keys()).map(v => ({value: v})))
```

Answer (score 1):

For each number, you should append `{value: number}` to an array. Since this process is made for each number and we want an array as result, we can use map.

```
Array.from(Array(3).keys()).map(value => {return {value: value}})
```